# Как в MaterialAlertDialog с Radio Group сделать uncheck Radio Button?

Tags: android, android-customview, android-alertdialog, radiobutton

Есть EditText.

```
OnClick:
val position=-1
val customView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.custom_layout, null)  
if (editText.text.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
            for (i in array.indices) {
                if (tE.text.toString() == array[i])
                    position = i
            }
        }

for (i in array.indices) {
            val rb = RadioButton(this)
            rb.text = array[i]
            if (position == i) {
               rb.isChecked = true
            }
            rg.addView(rb)
        }

val dialog = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this, R.style.MyThemeOverlayAlertDialog)
            .setView(customView)
            .show()
```

В макете CustomView находится RadioGroup, который заполняется Radio Button - ами динамический, и один из них по результату условий

```
rb.isChecked = true       //checked rb
```

Когда выбираются другие `rb`, то выбранный `rb` не становится почему-то `unChecked`.
 Что я делаю не так?

Comment: чтобы понять, что не так, нужен, как минимум код того, где что то не так. у вас проблема с радиобатонами, но кода их создания и работы с ними нет в вопросе, а здесь нет экстрасенсов

Comment: @pavlofff, дополнил...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, может кому пригодится...
Ответ был прост:

```
val position = -1
val isExistRb = false
val customView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.custom_layout, null)  
if (editText.text.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
            for (i in array.indices) {
                if (tE.text.toString() == array[i])
                    position = i
            }
        }

for (i in array.indices) {
            val rb = RadioButton(this)
            rb.text = array[i]
            if (position == i) {
               isExistRb = true
            }
            rg.addView(rb)
        }

val dialog = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this, R.style.MyThemeOverlayAlertDialog)
            .setView(customView)
            .show()   
if (isExistsRb){
   (rg.getChildAt(position) as RadioButton).isChecked = true
}
```